# Order of $\epsilon$ and $x$ in the definition of pointwise convergence

Tags: predicate-logic, pointwise-convergence

The definition of pointwise convergence of a sequence of functions $\{f_n\}$ on a set $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ to a funtion $f$ is that $\forall x\in A$ the sequence $\{f_n(x)\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ converges to $f(x)$. That is,
$$\forall x\!\in\!A\ \ \forall\epsilon\!>\!0\ \ \exists N\!\in\!\mathbb{N}\ \ \forall n\!\geq\!N\ \ |f_n(x)-f(x)|\!<\!\epsilon$$
My question is: **Isn't it same as the one given below?**
$$\forall\epsilon\!>\!0\ \ \forall x\!\in\!A\ \ \exists N\!\in\!\mathbb{N}\ \ \forall n\!\geq\!N\ \ |f_n(x)-f(x)|\!<\!\epsilon$$
I think we should be able to change the order of two nearby universal quantifiers since the variables cannot depend on one another. But my guide says the order of $\forall x\!\in\!A$ and $\forall\epsilon\!>\!0$ matters here, and he mentioned that *there is a counterexample*. Am I missing something here?

Note1: We both knew that uniform convergence is different from point-wise convergence. He maintained that the above two are indeed different.

Note2: $\forall x\forall y$ is different from $\forall y\forall x$ if the domain for one of the variables is defined in terms of the other (eg: In the case of $\forall x\!\in\!\mathbb{N}\ \forall y\!\in\!\mathbb{N}\!-\!\{x\}$, it is evident that we cannot change the order). But except for this, I don't know any other problem that makes the two orders different. For, the two statements given above in equation environments, there is no issue of domain of one variable depending on the other. Is there any other problem?

Comment: You are right: the order matters for different quantifiers: $\forall \exists$ is not the same of $\exists \forall$. But $\forall x \forall y$ is the same as $\forall y \forall x$.

Comment: The only point can be a metter of "readibility": if we are defining the continuity in $x_0$ obviously we write $\forall \epsilon \in A \ldots$. Thus, if we want to assert that this holds for every $x \in A$, it is natural to quantify the previous with $\forall x \in A$.

Comment: I think your guide means there is a difference between your first formula and $\forall \varepsilon > 0\, \exists N \in \mathbb{N}: \forall n \ge N\, \forall x \in A, \lvert f_n(x) - f(x) \rvert < \varepsilon$.

Comment: @Gibbs No, we were discussing uniform convergence. So, it is clear he didn't mean that. And he said that definition of point-wise convergence is not equivalent to the second one i've written in the question.

Comment: The formula I mentioned in my comment is exactly the one defining uniform convergence.

Comment: See [Uniform convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_convergence#Definition) : $\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists N, \forall  x \in A \ldots$. See my first comment: this **is** different from: $\forall  x \in A, \forall \epsilon > 0, \exists N  \ldots$.

Comment: added notes 1,2 to clarify the question